# What are the alternatives for " schmutzige Wäsche in die Waschmaschine werfen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Vor dem Zubettgehen habe ich meine schmutzige Wäsche in die Waschmaschine geworfen, weil ich morgen arbeite.

What are alternatives for `werfen`? Can I use `reintun` or `stecken` in this context?

Comment: Apart from cr0's suggestions, you can also use: *Vor dem Zubettgehen habe ich meine Waschmaschine mit schmutziger Wäsche gefüllt, ...*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stecken` is definitely ok. You can also use `tun` without `rein` which will be in your case:

> Vor dem Zubettgehen habe ich meine schmutzige Wäsche in die Waschmaschine getan

However you should know that `tun` (present) is often avoided because it's some kind of children's language and not very sophisticated.

If your washing machine is very full you can use `stopfen`, too. I'm not 100% sure if `legen` is also used in the context of putting clothes in a washing machine.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich gebe meine Wäsche in die Waschmaschine.

Stecken and reintun is ok, but I would rarely use it. Werfen or legen really does not work for me.

Comment: I agree, "geben" would be the word of choice for me also.

Comment: I solely use *geben* when I bring my stuff to a laundry.